# Is this an equivalent way to define the $k$-th exterior power of an $R$-module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Let $T^k_R(M)$ be the $k$-th tensor power of $M$ over $R$.

The $k$-th exterior power is defined as $T^k_R(M)$ modulo the subspace generated by all pure tensors $m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_k$ such that $m_i=m_j$ for some $i \ne j$.

---

Let $W=\langle (m_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes m_k) + (m_{\tau(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes m_{\tau(k)}) \mid \tau=(ij) \in S_k \text{ is a transposition} \rangle$.

**Is the $k$-th exterior power (the set of alternating tensors) equal to $T^k_R(M)/W$?**

I find that $T^k_R(M)/W$ satisfies the universal property for alternating $R$-multilinear maps: that is, if $f: M^k \to P$ is a $R$-multilinear and alternating, then $f$ induces a linear map $\bar f: T^k_R(M)/W \to P$.

Comment: It is equivalent when $2$ is invertible in $R$. The invertibility of $2$ is required to obtain pure tensors with equal tensorands as linear combinations of your generators of $W$. If $2$ is not invertible in $R$, then $T^k_R\left(M\right)/W$ is not isomorphic to $\wedge^k_R\left(M\right)$. In the "worst case", $R$ is an $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra and $T^k_R\left(M\right)/W$ is the $k$-th symmetric power of $M$, because addition is the same as subtraction over $R$.